# Why are R.string.cancel/ok missing only in Java?

Tags: java, android

XML (works):

```
android:text="@android:string/ok"
android:text="@android:string/cancel"
```

Java (works):

```
R.string.some_string_that_I_have_added_to_strings_xml
```

Java (does NOT work: cannot find symbol variable cancel/ok):

```
R.string.cancel
R.string.ok
```

… even though they are used in an example at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs and show up at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string .

I have also tried to `import android.R.string;` with no difference.

So how come the compiler complains that they are missing and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are probably importing (on top of the file) `your.package.name.R`, there is no `ok` or `cancel` in it, so wrong reference when `R.string.ok`. When you add `import android.R.string;` then you have access to system values by `string.ok`, not `R.string.ok` (as you probably still importing apps `R` and all `R.string...` are referencing to it). try to use `android.R.string.cancel` straight in code, without any additional import, for forcing Android system resources, not app own.

you also may use `import android.R` instead own packages `R`, but note that then you have to write `your.package.name.some_string_that_I_have_added_to_strings_xml` in code for accessing own resources (as only one `R` may be imported, other ones must be written with full package). Much more convenient and most common way is to import own packages `R` on top of file, then use `R.string` prefix for own resources and short `android.R.string` "full" prefix for system resources in code

(also this expands to all other kinds of resources ofc)

Comment: Thanks! Well, I wasn't importing anything, but changing to `android.R.string.cancel` works. I see now that in the xml it's actually `@string/some_string_that_I_have_added_to_strings_xml` versus `@android:string/cancel`.

Answer (score 1):

If your strings are written inside values folder in strings.xml then you can access it like this:

strings.xml

```
<string name="OK">OK</string>
<string name="Cancel">Cancel</string>
```

XML layout

```
android:text="@string/OK"
android:text="@string/Cancel
```

Code:

This depends on where are you trying to call resources from. But inside Activity/Fragment you can do this

```
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.OK)
textView1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Cancel)
```

this will use strings from strings.xml. Shortcut for this inside Activity is

```
getString(R.string.OK)
```

There is no need for `'android.R.string'` This is for strings that are defined in your strings.xml and nothing else. Important to remember is that R.string.yourString returns INT and not STRING. That's why you need getString() to get String. Also, when you write `android.R.string.cancel` it will read from android built-in string resources and not your strings.xml file.

Comment: Oh, I know this, but I wanted to use the built-in values and couldn't figure out why it didn't work. :)

Comment: @LGT Oh, okay. I didn't really understand what were you doing. Then just use getString(android.R.string.ok) and it should work